# Using POST instead of GET

Tags: php, post

Maybe I don't understand English as well as I thought. I need some help. I read the other posts but I am still not able to send variables to another page using POST instead of GET. Please help me with this example:
I have two pages. The first one has a query (Users). Then I make a table with the results and using the following code I can send user id to another page where I can edit some information.

First page:

```
 <td><div align="center">
 <a href="Users_modify.php?id=<?php echo $row_Users['id'];?>">
 <img src="Icons/info-icon.png" width="20" height="20"></a></div></td>
```

Second page:

```
$colname_recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$colname_recordset1 = $_GET['id'];}
```

and after this I can use the variable to make a query.
With respect I ask you for a sample of the first page statement in order to be able to use POST on the second page. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Simple to google for examples of posting data (you don't even have a form element in your HTML).

Comment: Do you REALLY think it is easier to ask a question here than to search on Google? If I asked you could understand that I didn t found an answer! I am tired of smart guys telling us, the noobs, that we are stupid!

Comment: Don't take it personal nor take offense. It's my position that I'm being *helpful* by telling you that you need to [improve your research capabilities.](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+post+vs+get)

Comment: My programming abilities and English language is the problem. It is not the first time when I ask something after hours of searching on Google. The idea of the site is to help people that are not so skilled. The right answer was "You can only use $_POST on a form". This is what I missed. This answer is more helpful than a -1 and "go to Google" and it took, I think, the same time. I am a guy - :) I don t like to ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use $_POST on a form.

If it is associated in a link, you can use $_GET or you can use $_REQUEST to get the query string.

Answer (score 1):

You'll fill `$_POST` by using a form:

```
<form action="…" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="$id">
…
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

posting it by form

```
<form action="second page url" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id">
…
<input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Page

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
<input type="hidden" name="idField" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Second Page

```
<p> 
<?php
    echo $_POST["idField"];
?>
</p>
```

Comment: Multumesc. Thank you! My intention was to avoid to have in the address bar the id value because somebody could change the value there and then edit that user. My mistake in using POST was that I didn t have a form.